# When is a Cauchy surface non-compact?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematics, topology, causality

If we have a spacetime $(M,g)$ admitting some Cauchy surface $\mathcal{S}$, we know from [Geroch's splitting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geroch%27s_splitting_theorem) that $M = \mathcal{S}\times \mathbb{R}$. A standard result from topology is that the product of two topological spaces $X = A \times  B$ is compact iff both $A$ and $B$ are compact.

Applying this to $M$, we can conclude that $M$ is non-compact, since the real line $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

However, it might be the case that the Cauchy surface in question *is* compact. Are there any conditions that ensure (non-)compactness of $\mathcal{S}$?

Moreover, are there any arguments for whether compact Cauchy surfaces are more plausible than non-compact ones? Which one is more physical, and which one occurs more in practice?